# Problem 30 in the Exercises following Chapter 2 in Baby Rudin: How to immitate the proof of Theorem 2.43?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

Here's problem 30, the very last one, in the Exercises after Chapter 2 in Walter Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*, 3rd edition:

Imitate the proof of Theorem 2.43 to obtain the following result:

If $\mathbb{R}^k = \cup_{n=1}^\infty F_n$, where each $F_n$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^k$, then at least one $F_n$ has a non-empty interior.

*Equivalent statement*:

If $G_n$ is a dense open subset of $\mathbb{R}^k$, for each $n = 1, 2, 3, \ldots$, then $\cap_{n=1}^\infty G_n$ is not empty (in fact, it is dense in $\mathbb{R}^k$).

(This is a special case of Baire's Theorem; ...)

Now I have seen a proof of this result in a solutions manual to Babay Rudin, but I wonder how to obtain a proof like that of Theorem 2.43, as required by Rudin?

I think I have fully comprehended the proof of Theorem 2.43 and can even reproduce it with some effort.

However, I'm unable to make a connection between that proof and the proof I've seen of the above result.

Comment: "Suppose $V_n$ has been constructed", so that $\overline{V}_n \subset \bigcap_{k=1}^n G_k$. Now continue along the lines of the proof of 2.43.

Comment: @DanielFischer, I would really appreciate if you could just write out the complete solution for me. I'm not able to pick the hint, I'm afraid.